# How can i create a form to open subdomain with parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

This is a simple form but I am unable to solve the issue.

```
<form action="#">Enter Your Name:<input type="text"><input type="hidden" value=".storage.tricksbygoogle.com"><input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

I want to create a form on http://storage.tricksbygoogle.com so that when someone inputs text in the form, it should open a url corresponding to that text. Eg. If "NAME" was entered, the url that should be opened is http://NAME.storage.tricksbygoogle.com

I have tried everything, and don't know what to do now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout this snippet

```js
$('#submit').click(function(){
  var name = $('#name').val();
  var url = $('#url').val();
  window.location.href = "http://" + name + url;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
 Enter Your Name:<input type="text" id="name">
 <input type="hidden" id="url" value=".storage.tricksbygoogle.com">
 <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `click` event on submit button.On clicking get value of name and `concatenate` with `url`.Set new `url` to `action` attribute of your `form` and finally `submit` it.

```js
url = $("input[type='hidden']").val();

$("input[type='submit']").on('click',function(){
name = $("input[type='text']").val();
finalUrl = "http://"+name+"."+url;
$("#myform").attr('action',finalUrl);
$("#myform").submit();
console.log(finalUrl);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" id="myform">
 Enter Your Name:<input type="text">
 <input type="hidden" value="storage.tricksbygoogle.com">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: see in console your form is submiting with required url.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
     $(function(){
          $("#submitForm").click(function(){

            location.href=$("#Name").val()+$("#Hiddenlink").val();
          })
   })
  </script>


<form>
 Enter Your Name:<input type="text" id="Name">
 <input type="hidden" value=".storage.tricksbygoogle.com" id="Hiddenlink">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitForm">
</form>
```